# How to know if my cat has broken his paw

Tags: cats, health, injury

I have a little cat, aged between 2 and 3 months. He climbed the closet and jumped to the floor, started twisting his left paw, screamed as hard as he could and then he threw up a yellow tinted vomit. I live now in a place where there is no veterinarian. I just wrapped his paw in a bandage for now, but **how to know if he got a broken paw? And how to treat him?**

The height he jumped from was 2 meters / 6.5 feet. Could that have broken his bones?

I'm planing to take him to the veterinarian when my brother returns my bike in the evening, until then I'll appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the vet. Your cat's leg is not the biggest problem, but possible internal injury is. If a cat starts to throw up after a fall, it needs to be taken to a vet today. A broken leg is easy to fix, but internal injury is not.

I am not saying a broken leg is unproblematic, but it is possible for a vet to fix it. Internal injuries can be very dangerous, and you might have little time to get your cat to the vet.

Comment: thank you :) , i took him to veterinary and he said it was "artificial torsion" in his elbow and he gives him "Vetalog Parenteral" an anti-inflammatory and said try to not allow him to move to much, i tried but hes young and hes on fire moving and jumping everyplace i cant even catch him . and when i put him inside a box he start crying with woeful voice ! , his breed is 'California Spangled' which known as they Hyperactivity ,he love to be active all day . even when he's injured

Comment: a kitten will often have flexible bones so they do not break easy,but try to keep  him out of trouble he is still too young to have controll and he is still learning what he can or can not do.

Answer (score 1):

For a cat that young it's possible a fall from that height could have broken the paw if he landed awkwardly on it.

But this is really one for a vet, they'll be able to X-ray the paw to see if it is broken. That's the only real way to be sure.